# Qt/C++ Error handling

Tags: c++, qt, error-handling

I've been doing a lot of research about handling errors with Qt/C++ and I'm still as lost as when I started. Maybe I'm looking for an easy way out (like other languages provide). One, in particular, provides for an unhandled exception which I use religiously. When the program encounters a problem, it throws the unhandled exception so that I can create my own error report. That report gets sent from my customers machine to a server online which I then read later.

The problem that I'm having with C++ is that any error handling that's done has to be thought of BEFORE hand (think try/catch or massive conditionals). In my experience, problems in code are not thought of before hand else there wouldn't be a problem to begin with.

Writing a cross-platform application without a cross-platform error handling/reporting/trace mechanism is a little scary to me.

My question is: Is there any kind of Qt or C++ Specific "catch-all" error trapping mechanism that I can use in my application so that, if something does go wrong I can, at least, write a report before it crashes?

Example:

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
[...]

public slots:
 void add_clicked();
}

void MainWindow::add_clicked()
{
    QFileDialog dlg(this, Qt::Sheet);
    QString filename = dlg.getOpenFileName(this);

    if(!filename.isEmpty())
    {
        QStringList path = filename.split(QDir::separator());
        QString file = path.at(path.count()); // Index out of range assertion.

        if(!lst_tables->openDatabase(filename))
        {
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```

I want this error to be caught as an unhandled exception AND the application to quit without showing the user the default crash window on Windows/Mac operating system. I just want it to quit nicely after writing the assertion message to a file, etc.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Override [QCoreApplication::notify()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#notify) and add try-catch there. That, and something in main() covers most cases in my experience.

Here's sort-of how I do it. Note that I'm using C++ RTTI here, not Qt's version, but that's just for convenience in our apps. Also, we put up a `QMessageBox` with the info and a link to our log-file. You should expand according to your own needs.

```
bool QMyApplication::notify(QObject* receiver, QEvent* event)
{
    try {
        return QApplication::notify(receiver, event);
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        qFatal("Error %s sending event %s to object %s (%s)", 
            e.what(), typeid(*event).name(), qPrintable(receiver->objectName()),
            typeid(*receiver).name());
    } catch (...) {
        qFatal("Error <unknown> sending event %s to object %s (%s)", 
            typeid(*event).name(), qPrintable(receiver->objectName()),
            typeid(*receiver).name());
    }        

    // qFatal aborts, so this isn't really necessary
    // but you might continue if you use a different logging lib
    return false;
}
```

In addition, we use the `__try`, `__except` on Windows to catch asynchronous exceptions (access violations). Google Breakpad could probably serve as a cross-platform substitute for that.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong because I'm getting NO love from any try-catch I do except when I use the throw command myself. So confusing. And even then, the application still crashes and tries to send an error report to Apple in this case. I'm trying to get the application to quit gracefully.

Comment: I have added some clarification and code to the original post.

Comment: @Shigon: For Mac you need a different mechanism to catch crashes. Search Google or SO for it, or ask a more focused question here on SO. How to do that isn't primarly Qt-related, since this question answers where in the Qt framework to put these crash-handlers.

Comment: Is this approach safe? Qt claims that it cannot handle exceptions propagated through signals and slots: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html#signals-and-slots

Comment: @Mikhail: Not in the sense that you should rely on this for error management in your app. However, as a debugging tool, it's quite useful to catch and report errors close to where they occur. Signal/slot use events only in queued mode (across threads)

Answer (score 12):

You can put a catch (...) in or around main()  Here's around:

```
int main() try
{
  ...
}
catch (std::exception & e)
{
  // do something with what...
}
catch (...)
{
  // someone threw something undecypherable
}
```

Comment: Also, adding c-style exception handling catches Access Violations, Stack Overflow, and a few more useful exceptions.

Comment: @Marcus you can only catch access violations and stack overflow via exception handling on Windows using MSVC, as far as I know... it's not portable.

Comment: @Jerkface: True. I don't know why I was assuming Windows in this case. :-|

Answer (score 6):

[Google Breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) is a cross-platform application error reporting framework. Maybe it helps?

(I haven't tried it in our c++/qt apps yet, but I'd love to get around to it someday...)

Answer (score 2):

Qt doesn't generally use, or entirely support exception throwing (if you can belive that!)

Check out these links:

[Why doesn't Qt use exception handling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548951/why-doesnt-qt-use-exception-handling)

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html

That said, the answers from @Crazy Eddie and @Macke are pretty good, but don't always work.  In particular, I found you can't use either of them from a slot function you've invoked from QML.  So, I created a hacky work around for this problem.  *Use this in conjunction with theirs - not in place of it.

First, I created class derived from QException, which I'll skip over here, but is something you'll probably want to do.  In this post, I just refer to it as "MyQException".

Anyway, add this header for a class called `QmlSlotThrower`:

```
#ifndef QMLSLOTTHROWER_H
#define QMLSLOTTHROWER_H

#include "MyQException.h"

class QmlSlotThrower
{
public:
    static QmlSlotThrower *get()
    {
        static QmlSlotThrower instance;
        return &instance;
    }
    QmlSlotThrower( QmlSlotThrower const& ) = delete;
    void operator=( QmlSlotThrower const& ) = delete;

    void throwToTop( const MyQException &exception );

private:
    QmlSlotThrower(){}
};
static QmlSlotThrower *qmlSlotThrower = QmlSlotThrower::get();

#define throwFromQmlSlot( exc ) qmlSlotThrower->throwToTop( exc ); return;

#endif // QMLSLOTTHROWER_H
```

Then, it's cpp:

```
#include "QmlSlotThrower.h"
#include <QTimer>

class AsynchronousThrower: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
    void throwThis( const MyQException &exception )
    {
        exception_ = exception;
        QTimer::singleShot( 0, this, SLOT( throwIt() ) );
    }
private slots:
    void throwIt(){ throw exception_; }
private:
    MyQException exception_;
};
static AsynchronousThrower asycnThrower;

// This is needed to allow the Q_OBJECT macro
// to work in the private classes
#include "QmlSlotThrower.moc"

// --------------------------------

void QmlSlotThrower::throwToTop( const MyQException &exception )
{ asycnThrower.throwThis( exception ); }
```

Finally, here's an example implementation:

```
void someQMLSlot()
{
    // Qt has been progressively adding exception handling
    // support, but you still cannot throw from a QML
    // triggered slot. It causes an uncatchable fatal error!

    // As a general rule, don't throw in Qt unless you are
    // certain something is there to catch it.  You cannot
    // count on an uncaught exception handler at a top level
    // to always work.  This QML problem is a perfect example.

    // So this is not an option here!
    //throw MyQException( "Something terrible occured!" );

    // This work around, however, can be used instead!
    //throwFromQmlSlot( MyQException( "Something terrible occured!" ) )

    // Or, to be more robust in illustrating how you can still use
    // normal throws from nested functions even, you can do this:
    try{ throw MyQException( "Something terrible occured!" ); }
    catch( const MyQException &e) { throwFromQmlSlot( e ) }

    qDebug() << "YOU SHOULD NEVER SEE THIS!!";
}
```

ONLY USE THE MACRO DIRECTLY FROM YOUR SLOT!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer error handling using exceptions.
Please find the below sample code:

```
ErrorStatus ExplodeToLine()
{
    var errorStatus = new ErrorStatus();

    try
    {
        errorStatus = fun();

        if (!errorStatus.ok())
        {
            throw new VicException(L"fun failed");
        }


        errorStatus = fun1();

        if (!errorStatus.ok())
        {
            throw new VicException(L"fun1 failed");
        }


        errorStatus = fun2();

        if (!errorStatus.ok())
        {
            throw new VicException(L"fun2 failed");
        }

        errorStatus.setError(ErrorType.OK);
    }
    catch (VicException vicExp)
    {
        Log(vicExp.errorMsg());
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Log(exp.errorMsg());
    }

    return error_status;
}
```