# QTcpSocket::write - how to write large files?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp, qtcpsocket

The qt documentation for [QIODevice::Write](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) says:

```
qint64 QIODevice::write(const char *data, qint64 maxSize)
```

> Writes at most maxSize bytes of data from data to the device. Returns the number of bytes that were actually written, or -1 if an error occurred.

But every code sample I found online seems to use this as follows:

```
QByteArray block;
... fill the block...
socket->write(block);
```

or as follows

```
QByteArray block;
... fill the block...
auto written_bytes = socket->write(block);
if(written_bytes < block.size())
   throw error()..
```

Suppose I have a large file (let's say, 2 GB) to send, should I use the first or the latter approach? I doubt 2GBs can be sent in just one chunk over TCP, right?

Or should I rather use something like the following?

```
QByteArray block;
... fill the block with 2GB of data...
auto written_bytes = 0;
while(written_bytes < 2GB) {
    // Restart each time where we previously left
    written_bytes += socket->write(block + written_bytes, 2GB - written_bytes);
}
```

I'm quite confused

Comment: Practical TCP/IP packet size (MTU over ethernet) is about 1500 bytes, so your data is going to chunked.  Write what is most obvious to you and easy to maintain.

Comment: Oh, so is it absolutely safe/reasonable for let's say a small "ping" of 5-6 bytes, to just throw an error if `write` couldn't write those 5-6 bytes?

Comment: Reads/Writes will block unless you are using non-blocking sockets.

Comment: I think it is also a bad idea to have 2GB of data in a `QByteArray`, you need to read and send data in chunks. . .

Comment: @RichardCritten This is Qt. Sockets are asynchronous by default.

Comment: You are looking for `splice(2)` (http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice). Not sure if there is an equivalent in Qt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep reading the file in reasonably sized chunks, and feed these chunks to the socket. You can adjust the chunk size on the fly to keep the socket streaming with small overhead, i.e. your code that reacts to low transmit buffer watermark shouldn't be active more than a dozen times per second or so. For very large files, as is in your case, aim for a refill once per second.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20864012/1329652) for example code.