# Qt: Catch application crash and display custom window

Tags: qt

I'd like our application to have a special window that catches crashes. Such window would have the ability to electronically send us the stack trace (on Mac), or the .dmp files on windows.

I can handle the window and its internal functionality -- but how does one catch an application crash in time to gracefully display a custom window?

I'm with Qt 4.8.5

Comment: have you checked the kde Dr. Konqi crash reporter how they do it? http://code.woboq.org/kde/kde-runtime/drkonqi/

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661883/qt-c-error-handling (luckily the new 5.1 docs site breaks all the links, so here is the live link to notify() http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#notify )  Notify should catch most exceptions that result in crashes, I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - with crash I understand things like access violation, division by 0 etc., not exceptions that you throw yourself - these can be handled with implementing `QApplication::notify`. If you need platform independent solution then i guess you would have to make a wrapper for the functionality on each platform:

- Un Linux, Mac, install a signal handler and show the window from
  there displaying maybe some optional signal info etc.
- On Windows I guess you could wrap everything with

  `__try { ... } __except { ... }`

Maybe you can subclass the QApplication and in your class actually handle the signal handler installation / add try-except handlers (depending on the platform) and then call some generic method where you do all setup and begin the event loop. That is just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

Working with Qt 4 years ago, I was in need of the same functionality.

Don't reinvent the wheel. I used Crashrpt with success. Comes with much needed features for user support.

https://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/

Comment: Yeah, found this with Google before writing the answer but isn't this Windows only?

Answer (score 1):

Not all crashes can be try-catched. Checkout this repo:
https://github.com/KandaoVR/qt-breakpad

> 1. This a demo to handle c++ crash with [google breakpad](https://github.com/google/breakpad) and launch a Qt app to send crash log back to server.
> 2. Most of the code are extracted from [Qt Creator](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator) project.
> 3. The Demo includes a `QtBreakpadDemo` which crashes, launching the `QtCrashHandler` afterwards.